# jbas015852 could not index class java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unknown tag

Tags: java, jboss6.x

This error happens when deploying to a local JBOSS server. Is there a way to resolve this warning?

> 22:31:22,992 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-13) JBAS015852: Could not index class com/company/core/security/AuthRealm.class at /C:/DevTools/jboss-eap-6.3/bin/content/platform-ws-0.1.war/WEB-INF/lib/com.company.platform-platform-core-0.1.jar: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unknown tag! pos=20 poolCount = 133
>       at org.jboss.jandex.Indexer.processConstantPool(Indexer.java:606) [jandex-1.0.3.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.0.3.Final-redhat-2]
>       at org.jboss.jandex.Indexer.index(Indexer.java:640) [jandex-1.0.3.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.0.3.Final-redhat-2]
>       at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.annotation.ResourceRootIndexer.indexResourceRoot(ResourceRootIndexer.java:100) [jboss-as-server-7.4.0.Final-redhat-19.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-19]
>       at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.annotation.AnnotationIndexProcessor.deploy(AnnotationIndexProcessor.java:51) [jboss-as-server-7.4.0.Final-redhat-19.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-19]
>       at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:159) [jboss-as-server-7.4.0.Final-redhat-19.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-19]
>       at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1980) [jboss-msc-1.1.5.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.5.Final-redhat-1]
>       at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1913) [jboss-msc-1.1.5.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.5.Final-redhat-1]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [rt.jar:1.8.0_31]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [rt.jar:1.8.0_31]
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_31]

An explanation of what is going on would be much appreciated, too.

Comment: The error seems to say that this class is corrupt: com/company/core/security/AuthRealm.class. Try rebuilding your application.

Comment: Getting this too. JBoss AS 7, Java 7. Luckily it appears to be just a warning. Seems to deploy ok. Started happening when I added tika jar file to war file.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I'm using JBoss EAP 6.3 with patch 6.3.3 but to solve the problem I need to use jandex from JBoss EAP 6.4. I just replace "jandex-1.0.3.Final-redhat-2.jar" for "jandex-1.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar" in JBoss modules and problem was solved.

There is a issue in JBoss of it, maybe problems with Java 8 or lambda expressions that Jandex can´t index. See this [link](https://developer.jboss.org/thread/239009?start=15&tstart=0) 
This is the link of the issue Bug [1193113](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1193113)
I hope that help you

Comment: @Carlos:  I tried this fix but didnot work out, i am using Jboss7.1.0 and still facing this issue. 
Error: [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYSRV0003: Could not index class module-info.class at //xxxxxx.war/WEB-INF/lib/log4j-api-2.10.0.jar: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unknown tag! pos=4 poolCount = 24
at org.jboss.jandex.Indexer.processConstantPool(Indexer.java:665)
at org.jboss.jandex.Indexer.index(Indexer.java:699)
at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.annotation.ResourceRootIndexer.indexResourceRoot(ResourceRootIndexer.java:99)

Comment: I've got the same problem with JBoss EAP 6.4.20 and jandex 1.2.5.Final-redhat-1

Comment: Have you tried the last version of jandex 1.2.4.Final or 2.0.5.Final ? 
https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/service/local/repositories/central/content/org/jboss/jandex/2.0.5.Final/jandex-1.2.4.Final.jar

https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/service/local/repositories/central/content/org/jboss/jandex/2.0.5.Final/jandex-2.0.5.Final.jar

Are you using the last Java or Java 8 ?

Comment: I'm using JBoss EAP 7.1, Java 8. I updated the latest 2.0.5.Final but still got the issue

Comment: @DineshKumar have you got the solution ? I am facing same problem with JBoss EAP 7.1, Java 8, jandex-1.2.2.Final-redhat-1

Comment: @DineshKumar have you got the solution ? I am facing same problem with JBoss EAP 7.1, Java 8

Comment: @DineshKumar any luck with the issue? i am facing the same problem. Thanks