# Could not index class module-info.class

Tags: java

web service calls failing with below error.

ERROR [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (default task-43) RESTEASY002010: Failed to execute: javax.ws.rs.NotAuthorizedException: HTTP 401 Unauthorized

Also getting below warning in server logs.

Could not index class module-info.class at /C:/econiq-github/repository/Local/acme/EconiqASTest/content/econiq.ear/lib/jaxb-api-2.3.0.jar: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unknown tag! pos=4 poolCount = 32

Answer (score 0):

The two problems you mentioned are very likely unrelated:

- The error you have seems pretty straight forward: you don't have the required permissions
- The warning you have is the same as this one : [jbas015852 could not index class java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unknown tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28935841/jbas015852-could-not-index-class-java-lang-illegalstateexception-unknown-tag)