# Log4j 2.16.0 java 8

Tags: java, log4j

Due the issue on log4j (CVE-2021-44228) I migrate some apps to log4j 2.15.0 (using JBoss EAP 7.1 with jdk 1.8.0_211-b12) without any issues.
I'd like now to migrate from log4j 2.15.0 to 2.16.0.

When I try it I've the following error

```
 15:20:59,361 WARN [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread
 1-8) WFLYSRV0003: Could not index class
 META-INF/versions/9/module-info.class  at
 /C:/jboss-eap-7.1/standalone/deployments/myApp-SNAPSHOT.war/WEB-INF/lib/log4j-api-2.16.0.jar:
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unknown tag! pos=4 poolCount = 32 at
 org.jboss.jandex.Indexer.processConstantPool(Indexer.java:1417) at
 org.jboss.jandex.Indexer.index(Indexer.java:1451) at
 org.jboss.as.server.deployment.annotation.ResourceRootIndexer.indexResourceRoot(ResourceRootIndexer.java:99)
 at
 org.jboss.as.server.deployment.annotation.AnnotationIndexProcessor.deploy(AnnotationIndexProcessor.java:51)
 at
 org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:165)
 at
 org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:2032)
 at
 org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1955)
 at
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
 at
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

It seems related with java version, especially because it's working for JBoss EAP 7.3 with jdk 11 but the official documentation says

*"Log4j 2.16.0 is the latest release of Log4j. As of Log4j 2.13.0 Log4j 2 requires Java 8 or greater at runtime. This release contains new features and fixes which can be found in the latest changes report."*

https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/index.html

Anyone with the same problem?

Edit: After rebuild all the porject I realize that this stack wasn't causing the crash. Since it's a warning I'll just ignore it

Comment: I have same problem with jdk8 and EAP 6.4. still researching what causing the issue.

Comment: Please note that I have same problem with 2.15.0.  looks like some jboss specific compatibility problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64790738/jboss-eap-7-0-java-lang-illegalstateexception-unknown-tag-pos-3-poolcount-20 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28935841/jbas015852-could-not-index-class-java-lang-illegalstateexception-unknown-tag

Comment: Having the same problem with log4j 2.16.0 with Wildfly 10

Comment: Just for the context, after rebuild all the project from scratch I could run the project.. I still have this message but it's a warning so I'll keep the warning and move on =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had same problem with log4j 2.16.0 and WildFly 10.1.
I tried to update WildFly from 10.1 to 13.0 and resolved that error.

The problem have been fixed on WildFly 13.0 ( https://issues.redhat.com/browse/WFLY-9608 ).

It seems that JBoss EAP 7.2 is equivalent to WildFly 14.0.

http://www.mastertheboss.com/jbossas/jboss-eap/what-is-the-difference-between-jboss-eap-wildfly-and-jboss-as/

So you should update JBoss EAP newer than 7.2.