# Error when trying to run a Java 8 project after working with a Java 17 project

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I've to work on different projects and one of them is using Java 8 and another Java 17. I was working with Java 17 last week and now I'm trying to revert my configurations to work with Java 8.

These are my configurations

```
$ mvn --version
Apache Maven 3.8.4 (9b656c72d54e5bacbed989b64718c159fe39b537)
Maven home: /usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.8.4/libexec
Java version: 1.8.0_251, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_251.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
Default locale: en_BR, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.16", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_251"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_251-b08)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.251-b08, mixed mode)
```

I removed all the folders inside ~/.m2 also.

My configs in IntelliJ are:

**Project Structure > Project > Project Settings > Project**

SDK: OpenJDK 1.8

Language Level: SDK Default

**Project Structure > Project > Project Settings > Modules**

Module SDK: Project SDK (OpenJDK 1.8)

**Preferences | Build, Execution, Deployment | Compiler | Java Compiler**

Project Bytecode: 8

**Preferences | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Maven | Importing**

JDK for importer: Use Project SDK

**Run/Debug Configurations > Tomcat 9.0.53**

JRE: OpenJDK 1.8

Am I missing something? Why this error is thrown?

```
-Dec-2021 12:05:30.631 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(4)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class [org.ocpsoft.rewrite.servlet.impl.RewriteServletContextListener]
    java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: META-INF/versions/9/module-info has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 53.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0 (unable to load class [META-INF.versions.9.module-info])
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2483)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:870)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1371)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1215)
        at com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.config.annotation.AbstractClassFinder.processClass(AbstractClassFinder.java:216)
        at com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.config.annotation.WebLibFinder.processJarFile(WebLibFinder.java:141)
        at com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.config.annotation.WebLibFinder.findClasses(WebLibFinder.java:85)
        at com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.config.spi.AnnotationConfigurationProvider.loadConfiguration(AnnotationConfigurationProvider.java:82)
        at com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.config.PrettyConfigurator.configure(PrettyConfigurator.java:63)
        at org.ocpsoft.rewrite.prettyfaces.PrettyConfigContextListener.contextInitialized(PrettyConfigContextListener.java:41)
        at org.ocpsoft.rewrite.servlet.impl.RewriteServletContextListener.contextInitialized(RewriteServletContextListener.java:38)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4768)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5230)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:726)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:698)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:696)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1783)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:293)
        at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
        at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:460)
        at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:408)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:293)
        at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
        at com.sun.jmx.remote.security.MBeanServerAccessController.invoke(MBeanServerAccessController.java:468)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1468)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:76)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1309)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1408)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:829)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:357)
        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:573)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:834)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:688)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:687)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Screenshots

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Where does META-INF/versions/9/module-info come from? Did you try to rebuild the project? If it's coming from some library, downgrade it to a version that is JDK 1.8 compatible.

Comment: @CrazyCoder  I've no idea, the project has only one file inside /META-INF and its context.xml. The build was completed successfully. 20/12/21 13:01 - Build completed successfully with 94 warnings in 48 sec, 2 ms

Comment: It's coming from org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.15.0, thanks!

Comment: Can you add this as an answer, please? This way I can mark my problem as solved. Thanks. @CrazyCoder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue appears to be with Tomcat being incompatible with log4j 2.15 when running on Java 8.

See the related issues for other app servers:

- [Log4j 2.16.0 java 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70353936/log4j-2-16-0-java-8)
- [java.lang.RuntimeException: Error scanning entry module-info.class from jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52716062/java-lang-runtimeexception-error-scanning-entry-module-info-class-from-jar)

Normally such issues are fixed by the app server update. If it's not possible, use log4j library without JEP-238.